# Solubility of oxygen in water with temperature, why does the change in solubility decrease around 40 °C?

Tags: solubility

Better set in context using a graph:

[image]

The solubility seems to fall quite persistently from 0 °C to 30 °C, then gradually slowing down in fall, then dropping faster and faster from 80 °C. Why does that change in drop happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relatively abrupt changes in slope (do a derivative plot to get an even more distinct picture of what is happening here) are due to changes in the solubility function dominating the solubility behavior at a given temperature and $\ce{O2}$ concentration.  For example, Henry's Law will describe the behavior at low $\ce{O2}$ concentrations.  As Henry's Law applies to the theoretical "infinite dilution" condition, this assumption falls apart at higher concentrations.

The greater the concentration of $\ce{O2}$ the more it departs from the ideal infinite solution assumed for Henry's Law behavior.  At higher concentrations, one or more of the different [gas laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws) then controls the solubility.  Based on your graph, it seems that there are three distinct regions, and thus three different gas laws defining the solubility of $\ce{O2}$ as a function of temperature.

One can also take an empirical approach to predicting the solubility based on experimental measurements.  [This website](http://antoine.frostburg.edu/chem/senese/101/solutions/faq/predicting-DO.shtml) has a live "$\ce{O2}$ solubility in water" calculator based on empirical data.  The authors use two different equations for two different temperature regimes: $\ce{0 ^oC - 30 ^oC and 30 ^oC to 50 ^oC}$.  So their $\ce{30 ^oC}$ cutoff seems to agree with the feature at that temperature in your plot.  I don't know the maximum temperatures / concentrations they used for their second equation.